# Reassign Javascript Function variable from HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that is triggered upon form submission:

```
var reusecard = true;
var form = document.getElementById('paymentForm');
Worldpay.useOwnForm({
  'clientKey': 'xxxxx',
  'form': form,
  'reusable': reusecard,
  'callback': function(status, response) {
    document.getElementById('paymentErrors').innerHTML = '';
    if (response.error) {             
      Worldpay.handleError(form, document.getElementById('paymentErrors'), response.error); 
      $("#paymentErrors").addClass("highlighted_box");
    } else {
      var token = response.token;
      Worldpay.formBuilder(form, 'input', 'hidden', 'token', token);
      form.submit();
    }
  }
});
```

I want to change the 'reusable' field to false, if the user changes a select box to "NO" on a form, using JQuery.

The ID of the select box is "reuse", which has 2 value choices, "YES" and "NO".

The JQuery I have been trying is:

```
$(function() {
$( "#reuse" ).change(function() {
    if ($("#reuse").val() == "YES") {
        reusecard = true;
    } else {
        reusecard = false;
    }
alert (reusecard);
});
});
```

Whenever the user changes the select box, the Javascript alert works fine, and displays the correct boolean value. However, when the function runs, it always takes the initially set value, and not the changed value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `var reusecard = true;` declared inside or outside the form submission function? If it is inside then of couse the value is always true every time the function runs

Comment: If you declare `var reusecard = true` outside your form submission function, it should work fine.  [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm8fwbr9/2/)

Comment: @devlincarnate it is outside the function, as a default value for when the user doesn't change the select box value.

Comment: Somebody answered yesterday, but deleted their answer. They mentioned changing
`'reusable': reusecard` to `'reusable': function() {return reusecard;}`. That appears to have worked, although I have no idea why.